# Implementation of a list view with 3 items, one text, one image and on radio button

Tags: java, android

I have some problems in implementing a list view with 3 items, one text, one image and on radio button. Could you please let me know how can we perform that.

I have 
String[] MovieName=new String[MovieNum]; //Has Movie Name Text
String[] MovieCover=new String[MovieNum]; // Has Movie Iamge URL

Can you help me with this with a probable sample code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is an example of a multicolumn listview with images and checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks Stephen I saw that, but no clue how to use Images, Radio Buttons for this

Comment: I changed the link. Found a better tutorial for your needs.